# Sitecore 6.6 Pipeline Fails to Run

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm following this guide for dynamic placeholders and cannot get my getPlaceholderRenderings pipeline to run.

I cannot see why this pipeline isn't working:

```
<getPlaceholderRenderings>
  <processor type="Site.CMS.Specialization.Pipelines.GetDynamicKeyAllowedRenderings, Site.CMS"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPlaceholderRenderings.GetAllowedRenderings, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPlaceholderRenderings.GetPredefinedRenderings, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPlaceholderRenderings.RemoveNonEditableRenderings, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.GetPlaceholderRenderings.GetPlaceholderRenderingsDialogUrl, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
</getPlaceholderRenderings>
```

My processor looks like this:

```
public class GetDynamicKeyAllowedRenderings : GetAllowedRenderings
{
    public new void Process(GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs args)
    {
        string placeholderKey = args.PlaceholderKey;

    }
}
```

At this stage I'm just testing that it runs. Which it doesn't.

I've done exactly what the guide says to do and yet this pipeline never runs. I've rebuilt countless times, recycled my application pool, and restarted IIS. None of which helps as when I debug my application with a break point in that pipeline it just isn't hit.

**Update**

I tested that my pipelines were being hit by adding the following code:

```
public class ExceptionThrower : HttpRequestProcessor
{
    public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
    {
        throw new Exception("ExceptionThrower");
    }
}
```

And this line to the config:

```
<httpRequestBegin>
  <processor type="Site.CMS.Specialization.Pipelines.ExceptionThrower, SCW.CMS" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.CheckIgnoreFlag, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.EnsureServerUrl, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
  .
  .
  .
</httpRequestBegin>
```

This gets hit and I see the exception.

If I add it to `getPlaceholderRenderings` it doesn't get hit.

The example I've been following (http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2011/August/Dynamic_Placeholder_Keys_Prototype) has exactly the same name, inheritance and parameters as my original code.

Comment: By this guide, I presume from the code you mean: http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2011/August/Dynamic_Placeholder_Keys_Prototype

Comment: Yes, I added a link but it apparently didn't make it..

Comment: Did you try this on a clean install on SC6.6 just to make sure it isn't something else in your code? It looks fine to me though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is caused by inheritance from `GetAllowedRenderings` class and `new` keyword. Try not to inherit from `GetAllowedRenderings` and see it the breakpoint is hit:

```
public class GetDynamicKeyAllowedRenderings
{
    public void Process(GetPlaceholderRenderingsArgs args)
    {
        string placeholderKey = args.PlaceholderKey;

    }
}
```

Check also if the `ShowConfig.aspx` page shows your rendering in the merged configuration: `http://localhost/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`

Comment: Yeah, my pipeline shows up in showconfig.aspx. I made the changes you suggested but it still just doesn't run.

Comment: Both the configuration and code look fine. Is your app running in debug or release mode? Maybe try to throw an exception instead of assigning value to a variable and see if the code is executed?

Comment: Running in debug mode. I've added an exception but it doesn't get thrown. The code isn't being executed.. But why?

Comment: Can you try to add a custom processor to any other pipeline and see if anything happens? And just to confirm: your processor is the first one of the `getPlaceholderRenderings` pipeline processors in the merged configuration?

Comment: See the update in the main question (too much for a comment). And yes, it's the first one.

Comment: He's following the code from techphoria's post so the inheritance and new keyword is the same. If it is not working then most likely a 6.6 compatibility issue...

Comment: Thanks Jammykam. I've checked it in my Sitecore 6.6 update 4 application - same code and same configuration and the breakpoint is hit in **Edit** mode of **Page Editor**. @Jon could you explain when you expect this breakpoint to be hit? And does it hit for you in **Edit** mode of **Page Editor**?

Comment: It works in edit mode of page editor! I expected it to be run during normal page loads when the dynamic placeholders are working out which controls should be in them. Am I incorrect?

Comment: This is a quote from **Sitecore.config**: `<!-- Supports the "Add Rendering" dialog by determining renderings allowed for a placeholder. -->
    <getPlaceholderRenderings>`

Comment: This works only for the `Add Rendering` dialog which is used by `Page editor`. See more information in @trayek blog here http://trayek.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/placeholder-settings/